# Are commands for variable initialization ever used as expressions?

Tags: programming-languages, initialization

In C, the assignment command also returns the value assigned, so it is also an expression.

Similarly, initialization, which happens when defining a variable, also assigns a value to the newly created variable. In programming languages, does a command for initialization ever return a value, so it can be used as an expression?

Essentially, I am trying to find out if initialization is viewed as a special case of assignment.

Thanks.

Comment: Once compiled, almost all initializations are assignments... I'm not sure what you're asking here.

Comment: In programming languages, does a command for initialization ever return the value assigned

Comment: Return the value to _what_?

Comment: It seems you started your question with its answer. Initialisation is just the first assignment. Does that make it special?

Comment: @Telastyn I think the first part is referring to constructions like `a = (b = (c == d))`, where the assignment also returns a value.  So maybe the second part is something like `a = (b = new C())` ?  But yeah, that is just an assignment...

Answer (score 3):

In the typical imperative language, a variable declaration is a statement, not an expression, and therefore does not return a value. But this is not the case for all languages. For example in Python, an initialization is the same as an assignment and returns the assigned value.

Answer (score 2):

There are so many languages that there are a couple of languages where declarations are expressions.

For example Perl. Lexically scoped variables are declared with `my`, e.g. `my $var`. This evaluates to an L-value that can be assigned to or used otherwise. A prominent example is the recommended usage of the `open` function. It takes three arguments `open(FILEHANDLE, MODE, FILENAME)`. The filehandle argument is a variable to which the filehandle object will be assigned, the rest is any string expression:

```
open(my $fh, '<', 'example.txt') or die $!;
```

The `open` functions returns success/failure, not the filehandle. To “return” the filehandle, it therefore uses out-parameters/call-by-reference.

The expression-level `my` operator is probably due to the design of the Perl bytecode: there's a separate instruction for assignment and declaration (makes sense, since many assignments are not variable initializations), and all instructions (even statements!) must evaluate to some value. Restricting `my` to a statement level would have then been artificial.

In C++, the syntax explicitly permits declarations in a conditional. This is convenient to check that a pointer you want to use is non-null:

```
if (Thing* something = get_something()) {
  do_stuff_with(*something);
}
```

Both Rust and Swift have a similar `if let` syntax to simplify pattern matching, though the value of the assignment isn't used in this case.

In general, imperative languages prefer to restrict declarations to statements, since this makes the code more obvious for humans. Where was a variable declared? What is the scope of a variable? That is easier to answer when you know where to look.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, typically a variable declaration that has an initializer does not produce a value like a regular assignment expression.

This is because in most languages, a variable declaration is a statement, not an expression.